# MaterialDesign TextInputLayout scaling problems

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

When I am running 360x640 it looks perfect, but when i go higher resolution it starts to look like that:

[image]

Code:

```
  // TOP INPUT
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dob_input_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="@string/date_of_birth"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_more_arrow"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bottom_text"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bottom_text"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_text">
    
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/dob_input_et"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:hint="@string/_12_15_2000"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/last_name_layout_input"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
    // BOTTOM INPUT
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber_input_layout"
                    style="@style/TextInputLayoutTransparent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="@string/phone_number"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_more_arrow"
                    app:endIconMode="custom">
    
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber_input_et"
                        style="@style/text_input_black_left"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:hint="@string/set_your_phone_number"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

What I tried is going with some custom padding between TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText but it changed nothing. First input is default style and the other one is custom, that's another thing that I thought was worth to look into.

---

EDIT

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

this little imp which is present in styles-v27 and above is making this effect, when i get rid of it, it's looking perfect.
Anyone has any idea what might be the reason for it?

Comment: which version of material components are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti 1.1.0

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti just tried with 1.2 beta and 1.3 alpha, all the same result